# Delta Lake 1.1.0 location in spark local mode not work properly

Tags: scala, apache-spark, delta-lake

I've updated some ETLs to spark 3.2.1 and delta lake 1.1.0. After doing this my local tests started to fail. After some debugging, I found that when I create an empty table with a specified location it is registered in the metastore with some prefix.
Let's say if try to create a table on the bronze DB with **spark-warehouse/users** as my specified location:

```
    spark.sql("""CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS bronze""")
    spark.sql("""CREATE TABLE bronze.users (
    |  name string,
    |  active boolean
    |)
    |USING delta
    |LOCATION 'spark-warehouse/users'""".stripMargin)
```

I end up with:
**spark-warehouse/bronze.db/spark-warehouse/users** registered on the metastore but with the actual files in spark-warehouse/users! This makes any query to the table fail.

I generated a sample repository: https://github.com/adrianabreu/delta-1.1.0-table-location-error-example/blob/master/src/test/scala/example/HelloSpec.scala

Comment: Looks like a bug even in 2.0.0rc1. Recommend reporting it at https://github.com/delta-io/delta/issues.